# Beta track app is not showing on installed apps list and update list

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

My app is published to beta track. I can find it on play market and install it. But app does not appear on "Installed" list of Play Market app and does not show up on "Updates" list. If there is an update, I can find it manually in play market and update from app page. In-app updates do not trigger. I asked my users about this issue and have 4 devices with same behavior and one that functions normally.

All functioned normally while app was on internal track. Internal track is now closed.

I tried following actions without any success:

- reistalling my app;
- clearing data and cache for play market app
- resetting updates and reistalling them for play market app.

What could be the case and is there a way to fix this?